# db_insert() returns wrong key

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to migrate from drupal_write_record() to db_insert() / db_update(),
but db_insert() returns a weird key instead of the last inserted key.

On an empty table, I'm doing an insert, and instead of real row number (suppose to be 1, right?), I'm getting a wrong one.

```
$fields['created'] = REQUEST_TIME;
$fields['uid'] = 1;
$insert = db_insert('table')->fields($fields);
$last_insert_id = $insert->execute(); // suppose to be 1, but = 43587087
```

Any ideas?
Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

The autonumber isn't related to the number of records in the table, but rather the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of the table's primary key column.

If you have a completely new table, and add 100 rows, the next ID will be 101. If you just remove all the rows in that table the next ID will *still* be 101, unless you `TRUNCATE` the table, or [reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73849/starts-with-a-larger-ubercart-order-number/73850#73850).

For an easy way to test, fire up your preferred DB client, and insert a record into the database. If you get `1` as the next insert ID, there's a bug with your Drupal installation/DB engine. If not, it's just what's mentioned above.

Comment: I'm referring to a new truncated table, and the ID I can see in the DB is 1. So what bug are you talking about? using drupal_write_record() works perfect, returning the correct ID on the same installation / db engine.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense, [`drupal_write_record()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) _uses_ the return value from `db_insert()` explicitly, so there wouldn't logically be any difference. I'm not talking about any bug in particular, I just know this isn't an issue on a standard Drupal/server install so there must be something non-standard about your setup

Comment: No it's not. drupal_write_record() uses db_insert() for the InsertQuery, but uses Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID to return last ID, while db_insert() uses InsertQuery::execute() function to return ID.

Comment: No it doesn't, it uses `if ($query_return = $query->execute()) {`. The return option is checked against `Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID`, but that constant is not used to determine the new ID in any way

Comment: Just wondering - is there only one AI column in this table? And key isn't composite? Drupal don't like composite PKs.

Comment: So please explain this: http://postimg.org/image/5w44t7wot/

Comment: As I already explained, I _can't_ explain that because it's non-standard behaviour :) Hence my guess that you're experiencing some sort of bug. _Or_ you're using composite primary keys as @Mołot suggested and that's causing the issue

Comment: @Mołot see my screeshot, using standard 'accesslog' table to demonstrate. Only 1 PK there.

Comment: @Clive, thanx man, I'll file a bug then...

Comment: @alechko No probs hope you get it sorted - if you do, I'd be very interested to hear back what the problem was

Comment: opened issue at http://drupal.org/node/2001538